# How does mlock() work with hibernation?

Tags: linux, memory, posix, hibernation

Quoting the Linux Programmer's Manual (`man 2 mlock`):

> `mlock()`, `mlock2()`, and `mlockall()` lock part or all of the calling process's virtual address space into RAM, preventing that memory from being paged to the swap area.

How does this work with respect to hibernation? Can a process using `mlock()` be hibernated at all? What are the semantics after resuming from hibernation?

Comment: See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe: **By nature, hibernation must write the whole RAM to the disk -- this includes pages which were mlocked,**

Comment: @Barmar your comment is wrong, I explained that in the answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41524790/952234). I think that for most Linux systems mlock doesn't allow hybernation to swap locked pages, but I can't guarantee the percentage though.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your system.
Linux manual for `mlock` [says](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html):

> Be aware that the suspend mode on laptops and
>          some desktop computers will save a copy of the system's RAM to disk,
>          regardless of memory locks.

Some tools are really affected by `mlock`:

- A suspend tool `swsusp` says it [can't hybernate](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/swsusp.txt) `mlock`-ed pages.
- A cryptographic tool `armory`, which uses `mlock`, [can't be
  restored](https://bitcointa.lk/threads/armory-discussion-thread.41475/page-192) after hybernation:

> 1- I hibernate the laptop with Armory opened.
>   2- I back from hibernate.
>   3- Armory doesnt syncronize. (To syncronize again I need to restart Armory).